# sublime text 3 is slow in 14.04(vmware), but smooth in 12.04(vmware)

Tags: 14.04

sublime text 3 is slow in 14.04(vmware), but smooth in 12.04(vmware)
,with same settings
other apps works fine in 14.04, just sublime text 3 is pretty slow, if the file is bigger, even slower.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the VMware Tools? (VMware Fusion -> Virtual Machine -> Reinstall VMware Tools) For me that solves several performance related issues. Also check how much resources you give to the vm. I gave it 4 cores and 4GB of RAM. I'm running 14.04 in VMware Fusion and ST3 runs very well.

Comment: thank you, I still do not know the solution, but ubuntu 14.04.3 x64 do fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, yea. I'm running the 64bit version too. Forgot to mention. I think 64bit is standard these days. :) Glad the problem is solved for you.